# Matlab - Figure Automatically Resizes (gui_mainfcn)

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I've built a GUI, and on startup (OpeningFcn), I maximize it (by setting position to [0 0.0463 1 0.8958]). However, when the GUI loads, its position changes (shifts a little to the right, and downwards).

Using debug, I've traced the line of code which does the resizing:

```
if ~gui_Exported
            gui_hFigure = local_openfig(gui_State.gui_Name, 'reuse',gui_Visible);
```

in the gui_mainfcn function, which comes after OpeningFcn is done executing.

Can someone explain to me what does this code means, and how can I prevent it from resizing my figure on startup?

Comment: How are you setting the `Position` property in the opening function? What is the `Units` property setting of your main GUI window?